# Mod-rewrite for GET parameter on subdomains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite a subdomain (NOT REDIRECT) to a **$_GET** parameter as such:

**Desired result:**

```
http://go.example.bz/link/abcde   ->   http://example.bz/go/link?id=abcde
or
http://go.example.bz/hrm/employee/8   ->   http://example.bz/go/hrm/employee?id=8
```

What's currently working:

```
http://example.bz/go/link/abcde -> http://example.bz/go/link?id=abcde
and
http://example.bz/go/hrm/employee/8 -> http://example.bz/go/hrm/employee?id=8
```

with this .htaccess in the root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^go/link.php/([^/\.]+)/?$ go/link.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^go/hrm/employee.php/([^/\.]+)/?$ go/hrm/employee.php?parameter=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

AddCharset UTF-8 .php
Options -Indexes
```

and this is how I redirect the subdomain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
   Servername go.example.bz DocumentRoot /var/www/go
</VirtualHost>
```

**I do not want to redirect** to the -> destination, rather to keep the http://go.example.bz/link/abcde url but have the results of the /link?abcde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured that my problem came from not remove .php extension from subdomain URLs of which I found an answer here https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/remove-php-extension-from-subdomain-urls/ and then I alternated my RewriteRules as such:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^go/link/([^/\.]+)/?$ go/link.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^go/hrm/employee/([^/\.]+)/?$ go/hrm/employee.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^go\.example\.bz$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.go\.example\.bz$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/tgc\.bz\/go" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php

AddCharset UTF-8 .php
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: But how is it doing this: `http://go.example.bz/hrm/employee/8   ->   http://example.bz/go/hrm/employee?id=8`?

Comment: I replaced parameter with id

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(link)/(.+)$ http://%2/%1/$1?id=$2 [NC,L,QSA,R=302]
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to change any results (500) i am getting. Here is the full .htaccess file: http://pastebin.com/rbY5v2Cf

Comment: Is it possible you can explain me how it works so that I could alternate it to fit my needs such as subdirectories etc.

Comment: I have answered as per your requirement in question i.e. `http://go.example.com/link/abcde   ->   http://example.com/go/link?id=abcde`. Here `%1` is the value being captured from first component of subdomain i.e. `go`. `%2` is `example.com`. Then `$1` is `(link)` and part after `link/` is captured in `$2`.

Comment: My .htaccess: http://pastebin.com/9jybVSUs Error: 404 Error.log: File does not exist: /var/www/go/link This works fine: http://example.com/go/link?id=test

Comment: I did, thank you. Not knowing or understanding how though. A clear answer if you do have time, for the masses to learn why and what worked, where I can also award the bounty.

Comment: Are `DocumentRoot` for `go.example.bz` and `example.bz` pointing to the same directory in your Apache config?

Comment: No. example.bz points to /var/www/ and go.example.bz to /var/www/go/

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^go.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*)$ http://example.com/go/$1?id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: This would redirect http://go.example.com/link to > http://example.com/go/go?id=link

Comment: @jQuerybeast  `go.example.com/link` doesn't match the rule above.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^go.example.com$
RewriteRule ^link/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ http://example.com/go/link?id=$1 [P]
```

Comment: This works: http://example.com/go/link?id=abcde but this throws 500 error http://go.example.com/link/abcde

Comment: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the$

Comment: Here is my full .htaccess file: pastebin.com/rbY5v2Cf

Comment: sorry, I can/t see the above rule in this pastebin

Comment: I did the pastebin before hand, but i tried your rule

Comment: I see, but to check for loops I would need teh exact file, since even the position of rule in the file can be important

Comment: You mean the exact .htaccess file?

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/sRy5zqeL I gave you the exact .htaccess just replaced all my_domain with example. Note that my domain is .bz

Comment: Sorry, I can't fugure out what could be causing the redirect loop here, especially if `http://example.bz/go/hrm/employee.php?id=something` works fine

Comment: I found where the 500 error came from and fixed it, still your example still doesnt seem to work? please see updated question. thank you

Comment: With this .htaccess: http://pastebin.com/2cN0d5sk I get 404 and File does not exist: /var/www/go/link in the error.log